# werid regexp always return ture

Tags: javascript, regex

I have met a weird regexp expression as following:

```
var a=/abc|/
```

which always return true when tested with other string.

```
a.test('ddd')
result: true
```

I cannot understand how that happened. since after the vertical bar, there is nothing.

Any explanation will be appreciated! thanks a lot!

Comment: because `ddd` includes *nothing*

Comment: The right side of the alternation (i.e. what comes after `|`) matches nothing.  Hence `ddd` matches because the pattern can match nothing.  If you used anchors this would not happen.

Comment: Please use regex101 for regex. They explain what your regex mean. https://regex101.com/r/z83DjQ/1/

Comment: any official document about null matches any position?

Answer (score 1):

In regular expressions the pipe character `|` stands for an OR operator. For example the regex `/abc|123/` will match the string `abc` or `123`. As a result regex `/abc|/` will match `abc` and *nothing* because there is nothing to match after the OR operator. Every other string will match *nothing*, including `ddd`.

Comment: null matches any position,not string